# Swift Error - ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: arrays, swift

I've a dobule array called upcomingTransactions.

```
var upcomingTransactions: [[Transaction]]
```

But when I'm trying to reach my cell from it, I got this error " ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" at

```
for (j, _) in upcomingTransactions[i] {
```

What I want is just to retrieve the cell from each section. I retrieve section with my i var but when I'm trying to catch cell by using a second var j, I need to put something but I don't see what. Here is my code :

```
var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
for i in 0..<upcomingTransactions.count {
    for (j, _) in upcomingTransactions[i] {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: i))
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, `i` is a `Transaction` not an `Int` the way you wrote the outer `if`

Comment: Well. I didn't get it. I'm sorry. What do you mean ? What sould I do in this case please ?

Comment: @Danyl They mean that `upcomingTransaction` is an **array of arrays**.

Comment: @the4kman I know that, this is why I'm asking how to catch the second element of this one corresponding to the cell in my case... any idea ?

Comment: This line: `for (j, _) in upcomingTransactions[i]` what do you think `upcomingTransactions[i]` is? it's `[Transaction]` right? so you can only enumerate it using `for j in`. It's not a tuple or dictionary...`for (j, _)` doesn't make sense

Comment: What is the declaration of `Transaction`? Unless it is an alias to a tuple, your code is not going to work.

Comment: You need to add `enumerated()` to `upcomingTransactions[i]` (`upcomingTransactions[i].enumerated()`) to be able to use `j` as row index.

Comment: @JeremyP   var upcomingTransactions: [[Transaction]] = []

Comment: @Danyl no the declaration of the type called `Transaction`

Comment: Thanks @LëshaTurkowski your answer. It's was a good clew for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for-each` iteration will result in `i` and `j` (assuming we fix the compile error) to be `Transaction` instances, as `for-each` iterates over the values in the array. If you want the indices than you have two options:

1. use `enumerated()`, which will also give you the index:

   ```
   var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
   for (i, arr) in upcomingTransactions.enumerated() {
       for (j, _) in arr.enumerated() {
           indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: j, section: i))
       }
   }
   ```
2. `map` the indices:

   ```
   let indexPaths = upcomingTransactions.enumerated().flatMap { (i, arr) in
      (0..<arr.count).map { j in 
          IndexPath(item: j, section: i) 
       }
   }
   ```

The second approach is a more functional one, while the first is a more imperative one. Personally I'd recommend the functional one because it uses only immutable entities.